# How to force TeamCity to run an nunit [Explicit] test

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, teamcity

So given a nunit test that has the `[Explicit]` attribute applied how can I force TeamCity to run that test?

Comment: TBH, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Basically, Explicit could be overridden by using categories. Then again, in theory, it could be overridden again by using Explicit on the test itself: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/EEpMFz6qHEw Haven't tested any of it though.

Comment: Update: I've tested this, and TC is not picking up explicit tests by category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the test specifically with a Teamcity build step.

Either running some script to run the test, or have the build step invoke the NUnit console app with the appropriate console arguments.

You'll have to include the nunit console app in source control, or otherwise have some way for TC to access it.